# How to dealloc CGPoint, CGRect variables?

Tags: objective-c, memory, core-graphics, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

I'm using Objective-C. I use automatic-ref-counting. I have a lot of `CGPoint` and `CGRect` variables in my code. I get memory errors. How can I dealloc after used.

Comment: Do you have `CGPoint` or `CGPoint*` variables? Similar question for `CGRect` and `CGRect*`

Comment: Please include a [MCVE](/help/mcve). This question is not answerable without one.

Comment: `CGPoint` and `CGRect` are both structs. Deallocating is not a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGPoint, CGRect are by default stack-allocated structures, which get allocated and deallocated automatically when the scope enclosing the variables begins, respectively when it ends. There's no need to deallocate those.

The only way these kind of variables can leak is if you declare variables as `CGPoint*` and `CGRect*` respectively and you manually allocate memory for them (using `malloc` or `calloc`). Or if you store them in `NSValue` objects which get retained indefinitely.

The point is that's not `ARC`'s fault for your memory usage, but rather your code.

Answer (score 1):

CGPoint and CGRect variables located in stack. They don't need to be deallocated.
They will be freed when program will go out from function, where they was created.